# Get all Resources with certain postfix in package (jar)

Tags: java, spring, jar

I'd like the have all jasper files in the given package:

```
ResourcePatternResolver res = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
res.getResources("classpath*:path/to/some/package/**/*.jasper");
```

All I get is an empty array.

When I try the pattern

```
"classpath*:**/*.jasper"
```

It finds all jasper files in the whole jar. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself...

```
res.getResources("classpath*:**/path/to/some/package/**/*.jasper");
```

Adding ** in front of the path solved the problem